# Starting VSCode with WSL Distro (from command line.)

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments, wsl2

is there a way to launch vscode from command line, and to tell it to start a new WSL window (using the default WSL distribution.)

I don't see an option in the CLI, and regardless of whether I launch code from Windows (PowerShell or CMD) or from within WSL (in my case, a Ubuntu distro), it brings VSCode up, and then I have *manually point and click* the option to create a new WSL window.

I'd rather just do something like `code --wsl` or some argument like that from the command line instead of pointing and clicking.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: When I launch `code .` from inside a WSL distribution, VSCode launches with the "Remote - WSL" extension active for that particular distribution.  You seem to be saying that it's opening in normal "Windows" mode even though you launched it from inside WSL, right?  If so, you may try deleting ~/.vscode-server` so that it gets regenerated the next time you launch.  Also confirm your `which code` from inside WSL.

Answer (score 0):

on the cmd-line:
`code --remote wsl+Ubuntu <path_on_wsl>`

You will have to replace <path_on_wsl> by an existing path on WSL.

You may have to replace Ubuntu by another name, depending on the distribution used with WSL.

For starters:

- install the WSL extension
- Ctrl+Shift+P to open the palette, start typing and select WSL:Connect to WSL
- Ctrl+Shift+P to open the palette, start typing and select WSL:Show Log. There I see `Resolving wsl+Ubuntu, resolveAttempt: 1`, so `wsl+Ubuntu` is the remote for me.
- Open the folder using the [Open Folder] button
- open the console and run `pwd` to see the full path of the directory. e.g. `/home/sascha`.